# Call rsync with args stored in a string

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rsync

This is the same script as the one cited in my mhddfs thread, I'd like to define the args according to some inputs, and call rasync afterwards. I currently came up with this but only the call to rsync is not working :

```
#!/bin/bash

INCLUDE=""
EXCLUDE=""
USER=""
HOST=""
KEY=""
FORCE=false
SHUTDOWN=false
DESTINATION=""
LASTFULL=""

while getopts u:h:k:s:o:f:e:i: option
do
    case "${option}" in
        u) USER=${OPTARG};;
        i) INCLUDE=${OPTARG};;
        e) EXCLUDE=${OPTARG};;
        h) HOST=${OPTARG};;
        k) KEY=${OPTARG};;
        s) SHUTDOWN=true;;
        o) DESTINATION=${OPTARG};;
        f) FORCE=true;
    esac
done

if [ -z $USER ] || [ -z $HOST ] || [ -z $DESTINATION ]
then
    echo "Usage : $0 <-u : user> <-h : host> <-t : type> <-o : output directory> [-k : key] [-s : shutdown]"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d "$DESTINATION/../Backup" ]
then
    if [ ! -d "$DESTINATION/Backup" ]
    then
        echo "Creating backup directory on target..."

        if ! mkdir "$DESTINATION/Backup"
        then
            echo "Could not create the backup directory. Exiting."
            exit 2
        fi
    fi
    DESTINATION="$DESTINATION/Backup"
fi

RSYNC_ARGS="-ravh -H --rsync-path=\"sudo rsync\" --append --progress --delete --safe-links"
if [ -f "$KEY" ]
then
    RSYNC_ARGS="$RSYNC_ARGS -e \"ssh -i $KEY\""
fi
if [ -f "$INCLUDE" ]
then
    echo "Including only files from $INCLUDE"
    RSYNC_ARGS="$RSYNC_ARGS --files-from=$INCLUDE"
fi
if [ -f "$EXCLUDE" ]
then
    echo "Excluding files from $EXCLUDE"
    RSYNC_ARGS="$RSYNC_ARGS --exclude-from=$EXCLUDE"
fi
if ! $FORCE
then
    LASTBACKUP=$(basename $(ls -td  $DESTINATION/*/ | sed "y/\t/\n/" | head -n 1 ) 2>/dev/null)
    echo "Processing backup based on --> $LASTBACKUP"
    RSYNC_ARGS="$RSYNC_ARGS --link-dest=../$LASTBACKUP"
else
    echo "Processing full backup"
fi

DESTINATION=$(echo "$DESTINATION/$(date '+%Y_%m_%d')" | sed "s#//#/#g")

rsync $RSYNC_ARGS $USER@$HOST:/ $DESTINATION 2> error.log

CODE=$?
if [ $CODE -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Backup done : $DESTINATION"
    exit 0
else
    echo "Rsync stopped with code $CODE"
    exit $CODE
fi
```

I get

```
Rsync stopped with code 1
```

error.log contains

```
Unexpected remote arg : <correct username>@<correct host>:/
```

When I echo the rsync call, copy paste it, it works

I know that $RSYNC_ARGS is messing this up but I don't know how to call it properly. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell parses quotes before expanding variables, so putting quotes in a variable's value doesn't do what you expect -- by the time they're in place, it's too late for them to do anything useful. See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for more details.

In cases like this, where you want to build a command's argument list dynamically, the best option is to store the arg list in an array. This way, the quotes get parsed when the array is created, each "word" gets stored as a separate array element, and if you reference the variable properly, the array elements get included in the command's argument list without any unwanted parsing:

```
rsync_args=(-ravh -H --rsync-path="sudo rsync" --append --progress --delete --safe-links)
if [ -f "$key" ]
then
    rsync_args+=(-e "ssh -i $key")
fi
if [ -f "$include" ]
then
    echo "Including only files from $include"
    rsync_args+=(--files-from="$include")
fi
# ... etc
rsync "${rsync_args[@]}" "$user@$host:/" "$destination" 2> error.log
```

Note that all the parentheses and `+=` in the assignments; and double-quotes, braces, and `[@]` when using the array, are *required* for this to work right.

BTW, you may notice that I've used lowercased all the variable names. Using uppercase variable names in the shell is dangerous, because there are a number of them with special meaning to the shell and/or other programs, and accidentally reusing one of those can have unintended effects. In fact, `$USER` and `$HOST` are like this (they get initialized to the current local username and hostname); reusing them *probably* won't cause trouble, but it's better to just avoid the issue by using lower- or mixed-case variable names. But you might want to add `user=$USER` at the beginning of the script so it'll default to using the same username if `-u` isn't specified.

Also, I added double-quotes around the variable references that didn't have them. You can often get away without them, but it's a good idea to use them to avoid potential problems. I recommend running your scripts through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net), since it's good at spotting common problems like this.

Comment: Hi, I updated my script bit it still does not work without eval... https://pastebin.com/LLDpb7ME

Comment: @JeanneD4RK Don't embed quotes in the values you're storing in the array; the array structure + double-quotes when it's expanded take care of this, and if you embed quotes in the values they're just treated as part of the data. For example, use `rsync_args+=(-e "ssh -i $key")` instead of `rsync_args+=(-e \"ssh -i "$key"\")`. My code sample above has more examples; follow the quote usage there.

Comment: Shellcheck told me to do this way. I'll try tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: @JeanneD4RK The only warning I see from shellcheck is about things like `rsync_args+=(--files-from="$include")`, where it warns that the "=" is literal; that's ok, it's *supposed* to be literal. If you want to avoid the warning, you can quote the entire string, like this: `rsync_args+=("--files-from=$include")`. This looks a little weird, but is fully equivalent (the `--files-from=` part of the string doesn't contain any shell metacharacters, so it doesn't matter if it's inside or outside the quotes) -- and shellcheck doesn't warn about it.

Comment: Another way to put it: quotes go *around* data, not *in* data. When you put multiple levels of quotes -- quotes within quotes -- you're putting shell syntax into your data, and that's what's causing trouble.

Comment: Thanks now it's working great. I also wrote the restore script and tested both, my 3yo server now has a backup ! lol

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to post until 40mins passed since my last post. In the meantime I used

```
eval rsync $RSYNC_ARGS $USER@$HOST:/ $DESTINATION 2> error.log
```

Which works perfectly.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend against using `eval` -- it blurs the line between code and data even more than usual in shell scripts, and this tends to create really bizarre bugs and security problems. See my answer for the better way to do it.